# Como hacer un login de 2 tablas diferentes?

Tags: php, laravel, nodejs, base-de-datos, login

Hola estoy tratando de hacer un proyecto en la cual consiste que el sistema debe registrarse 2 tipos de usuarios, los administradores y los clientes, realice 2 tablas diferentes para cada uno, el del administrador ya me funciona pero el de cliente no, ya que cuando trato de hacer login con los clientes que ya se registraron me dice que las credenciales no coinciden, es decir que si uso el correo de un cliente no lo acepta, pero si uso el correo y su password de un administrador me lleva directamente a las vistas del administrador algo que no quiero y quiero que me redireccione a las vistas que tengo para el cliente. Alguien que me indique donde es que me equivoque o me falte codigo.

Vista de login del ciudadano.

```
 <div class="col-6 col-sm-10 col-lg-6 col-md-6 mx-auto" style="position:absolute;right: 0;">
  <form action="{{ url('/loginCiudadano')}}" id="miForm" name="reportservice" method="post" 
     class="shadow-white rounded py-3 px-4" style="background-color:#5D6D7E">
      @csrf
       <div class="form-group">
           <font for="email" color="black">Correo electrónico</font>
           <input type="email" class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm border-0" id="email" 
            name="email" placeholder="example@hotmail.com" value="{{old('email')}}">
           {!! $errors->first('email', '<small class="text-danger">:message</small><br>')!!}
           </div>

          <div class="form-group">
             <font for="text" color="black">Contraseña</font>
             <input type="password" class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm border-0" 
                 name="password" id="extension" placeholder="********" value=" 
                 {{old('password')}}">
                      {!! $errors->first('password', '<small class="text- 
                 danger">:message</small><br>')!!}
               </div>
                 <br>
               <div class="container">
                 <center><button  type="submit" style="background-color:#e91e63" class="btn- 
                 outline-light btn-lg btn-block">Iniciar Sesión</button></center>
                </div>
                <p><center>_________________________________________</center></p>
                  <br>
               <div class="d-grid gap-2 col-3 mx-auto">
               <a href="{{ route('register') }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mb-1 active 
                 btn-outline-ligh" type="button"> Crear cuenta nueva</a>
               </div>
              </form>
              </div>
             </div>
```

Routes Web.

```
         Route::get('/inicio', function () {
              return view('inicio');
              });

              Route::get('/', function () {
              return view('PaginaOficial');
              });

              Route::post('/loginCiudadano', 'App\Http\Controllers\userCiudadanoController@login')->name('loginCiudadano');
              Route::get('/inicio','App\Http\Controllers\userCiudadanoController@secret')->name('inicio');


              Route::get('/reportarservicio','App\Http\Controllers\InicioController@index')->name('ReportarServicio');
              Route::get('/consulta','App\Http\Controllers\InicioController@consulta')->name('consulta');
              Route::put('/Cerrarsession','App\Http\Controllers\InicioController@logout')->name('Cerrarsession');
```

Controlador

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;


class userCiudadanoController extends Controller {
   use AuthenticatesUsers;

protected $loginView = 'views.PaginaOficial';
protected $guard = 'user_ciudadano';

function __construct(){
  $this->middleware('auth:ciudadanos', ['only' => ['secret']]);
}

public function authentication(){
  return redirect('/inicio');
}

public function secret(){
  return 'Bienvenido';
}
}
```

Modelo.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

//use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;


class UserCiudadano extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract {
use Authenticatable;

// use HasFactory;
protected $table = 'user_ciudadano';
protected $fillable = 
['nameCiud','email','telefono','curp','password','created_at','updated_at'];
 }
```

y el auth.

```
 <?php

 return [


'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],


'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],

'user_ciudadano' => [
  'driver' => 'session',
  'provider' => 'user_ciudadano',
],



'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],

    'user_ciudadano' => [
      'driver' => 'eloquent',
      'model' => App\Models\UserCiudadano::class,
    ]
    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
],
```

Les agradecería mucho su ayuda llevo mi 2 día atorado con el mismo detalle, ya busque e investigue y me fui guiando con tutoriales pero no consigo hagan login los clientes.

Comment: deberías mejor manejar una sola tabla con otra tabla que se le asigne un rol, ahora también veo que no estas modificando el guard, esto se hace es en el service provider no en el controlador

Answer (score 0):

No te compliques la vida con eso y mejor utiliza laravel spatie para manejar roles de usuario y mostrar lo que desees por roles.

https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission

Con esto puedes mostrar u ocultar contenido dependiendo del rol del usuario y redireccionarlo a donde desees dependiendo del rol manejado